# Access User Credential in Downstream services from Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a scenario that I have some microservices, cloud gateway and eureka server. All microservices and cloud gateway registered on the eureka server. Cloud gateway will securing all the downstream services. When any user want to access the service first it will fill out the username and password for authentication on the cloud gateway. If the user will be authentic then it will access the service by the gateway route that is already set in application.properties file but I want when the user will authentic and access the service then I can also get user authentic credential in downstream services or microservices that are behind the cloud gateway. In other word I want to getting principle values that is set on the gateway in downstream service. How do I implement this scenario.

Here is the [workflow](https://www.javainuse.com/cloud20-5-min.JPG)

Here is the cloud gateway configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class GatewaySecurityConfig{

     @Bean
        public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            UserDetails user = User.builder()
                    .username("user")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
            UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                    .username("admin")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                    .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                    .build();
            return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin);
        }
     
        @Bean
        public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .formLogin();
            return http.build();
        }
        
        
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
        }
        
}
```

Application.properties Configuration

```
server:
  port: 8080
 
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8083/eureka 

spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: userModule
        uri: lb://user
        predicates:
        - Path=/user/**
```

Comment: Why don't you create a filter and inject the Username and Password for the downstream requests?

Have a look at this for more insight

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410464/credentials-propagation-from-spring-cloud-gateway-to-underlying-service

Comment: Yeah!! I saw this but the code of this article is in Kotlin and i want it in Java. Is another way to do this or any option where we use this filter in Java.